# How can I link __sync_bool_compare_and_swap_16?

Tags: gcc, g++

I've got some code that uses the gcc builtin __sync_bool_compare_and_swap, which is mapped to __sync_bool_compare_and_swap_16 at linktime. But when I link this code I get a "undefined reference to `__sync_bool_compare_and_swap_16'" linker-error. What do I have to link ?

[EDIT]: I got it: I've to compile it with -march:x86-64. Interestingly this doesn't lead to intrinsic compilation, i.e. the compiler inserts the atomic operations appropriately; no, the code is just the same with the call to __sync_bool_compare_and_swap_16, but without a linker error. Does anynone understand this ?

Answer (score 0):

On my system, passing -march=native to gcc solved the problem.  I suspect (but am not sure) that is is because the 128-bit bool_compare_and_swap doesn't exist on all 64 bit cores (https://cbloomrants.blogspot.com/2010/05/05-29-10-lock-free-in-x64.html) and so -march=x86_64 (which is what my gcc defaults to) doesn't allow that.